# How to make font sharp in CSS?

Tags: css

Hello everyone I'm trying to use sharp property like photoshop in Css but how can I do ?

Here is my css

```
#login_text
{
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:18px;
 font-size:13pt;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Arial;

}
```

Comment: Are you using custom fonts or something? Why do you want to sharpen the fonts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In addition to the CSS3 `text-rendering` property AMK mentioned, there is also a Webkit (Chrome) specific hack for antialiasing: `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` (I believe the default value is `subpixel-antialiased`) which is nice to use since Webkit webfont rendering can be less than ideal on Windows machines in particular.  [A bit more info can be found here](http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing).

There is also an old proposed `font-smooth` CSS3 property ([see here](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font/#font-smooth-prop)) but as far as I know it is not implemented and doesn't do anything (at least not that I can see).

The sad reality is that you won't get Photoshop-quality font rendering on the web, especially not on a Windows machine.  You can make up for this by choosing good webfonts and picking font sizes that naturally scale nicely, but there's only so much you can do.

Comment: I think `-webkit-font-smoothing` is not relevant, since it is not supported on Windows platform.

Comment: ^ Microsoft web browsers

Answer (score 9):

Firefox 25 adds a new Mac-OS-only nonstandard property **-moz-osx-font-smoothing** equivilent to WebKit's -webkit-font-smoothing.

## element {

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

While there is no "sharp" value, I think that the CSS3 [`text-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-rendering) property is the best way to go. The effect is most noticeable on smaller font-sizes and doesn't make a big difference on large fonts.

Please note that there is very limited support for this but as far as I know it is the only method available.

Your other option (if you're using custom fonts) is to simply get higher quality vectors.

Comment: What effect would `text-rendering` have on sharpness? It affects other aspects of rendering.

Comment: Because the text rendering affects sharpness, even though it isn't stated anywhere that it does, it does.

Comment: @AMK, can you provide an example? Which value you would use for the property, and on which browser(s) would it have an effect on sharpness?

Comment: _Every_ browser with support for the text-rendering property. Assume every browser smooths fonts, setting text-rendering to `geometricPrecision` would _disable_ the font smoothing to make the glyphs as precise as possible thereby disabling all font-smoothing and making corners, etc. sharper.

Comment: @AMK, please provide actual evidence, as your speculation contradicts information like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-rendering

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela There's no need for "evidence", it's right in the name, text-_rendering_. This controls the rendering of text, if it doesn't, it's broken. Sharpness and smoothing are both aspects of rendering, plain and simple.